# What's the difference between に and を in these phrases?

Tags: particle-に, particle-を

I found these two phrases:

> 彼らは熊**を**[触]{さわ}る。
>
> 彼らは熊**に**触る。

I don't see the difference between them, since both mean "touching a bear."

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference.

Because 触る is intransitive, only に should technically be correct. However, the language has changed over time, and now you can find it with を sometimes.

Comment: Ah the ever-changing ways of living languages. Never fails to confuse and frustrate, eh? Kidding, kidding. >w< It's all fun and games once you get it.

Comment: Well, I learned something new today. d(^w^)

Comment: So, they have the exactly same meaning with no sightly difference?

Comment: でも・・・Don't touch me! は「私**を**触らないで」でなく「私**に**触らないで！」と言いますよね・・・一方で、電車の痴漢には「女性のお尻**に**触った」でなく「女性のお尻**を**触った」って言いますよね・・・