# What is the difference in meaning when 触る is used with に vs when it is used with を?

Tags: grammar, meaning

According to jisho.org, [触る is both transitive and intransitive](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A7%A6%E3%82%8B).

How is it that it can be both? Here are two example sentences from my dictionary:

> 僕の車を触らないでくれ。
> ぼくのカメラに触らないでくれ

What is the difference in nuance between these two sentences?

Comment: Does this answer your question?: [What's the difference between に and を in these phrases?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30500/5010) / [What is the difference between に触れる and を触れる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53202/5010)

Comment: I believe the accepted answer there is incorrect. See the comment there by @chocolate for a couple examples of how these usages can differ. Unfortunately, that comment does not answer *why* they differ.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't notice that you posted two links there in your comment. The second one does indeed answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: There may be a rule I'm not consciously aware of. For now, I can say に触る and を触る are interchangeable at least in your example sentences.